# Removing username field to Django AbstractBaseUser customize model - Unknown field(s) (username) specified for User

Tags: python, django-models, django-forms, django-users

I have a custom User model in which the primary key is the `email` field and this is the `USERNAME_FIELD` and `REQUIRED_FIELD` too. My user model is of this way:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    '''
    This is the username field which I've removed ...
    username = models.CharField(
        _('username'),
        max_length=30,
        primary_key=True,
        help_text=_('Required. 30 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only.'),
        validators=[
            RegexValidator(
                r'^[\w.ñ@+-]+$',
                _('Enter a valid username. This value may contain only '
                  'letters, numbers ' 'and @/./+/-/_ characters.')
            ),
        ],
        error_messages={
            'unique': _("A user with that username already exists."),
        },
    )
    '''

    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, primary_key=True)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email']
    objects = UserManager()
```

The `UserManager` class is:

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    use_in_migrations = True

    def _create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given email and password.
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The given email must be set')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')

        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)
```

Like I recently I've removed the `username` field, when I execute the `makemigrations` process, I get this error:

```
 File "/home/bgarcial/workspace/fuupbol_project/userprofiles/forms.py", line 26, in <module>
    class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
  File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/fuupbol2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 257, in __new__
    raise FieldError(message)
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (username) specified for User
```

What happen is that in my forms.py I am using the `UserCreationForm` class  to inherit from her, to create user in my admin in my `CustomUserCreationForm` class

class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = User

In my my `admin.py`

```
class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin,):
    form = CustomUserChangeForm
    # Here I call the CustomUserCreationForm which inherit from
    # UserCreationForm
    add_form = CustomUserCreationForm
    fieldsets = UserAdmin.fieldsets + (
        (
            None, {
                'fields':(
                  ...  some fields  ...
                )
            }
        ),
    )
```

In this admin.py file I call the CustomUserCreationForm which inherit from
`UserCreationForm` django pre-built class

What happen is that when I going to the `UserCreationForm` [source files](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L87) in their `class Meta` there is the `username` field in the `fields` attribute and the `field_classes` attribute

Is for this reason that the `username` field is persistent in my custom user model schema, really?

How to can remove the username without take in account this detail or follow using the `UserCreateForm` class and their implications ... ?

There is a better alternative to accomplish remove the `username` field in my `User` model?